# python tree .why it should call evaluate() method for every element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am little bit confuse why we should call evaluate method in this 
program
     like this self.right.evaluate() what is the role of including evaluate()

```
class exprnode(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def evaluate(self):
        if self.value == '+':
            return self.left.evaluate() + self.right.evaluate()
        elif self.value == '-':
            return self.left.evaluate() - self.right.evaluate()
        elif self.value == '*':
            return self.left.evaluate() * self.right.evaluate()
        elif self.value == '/':
            return self.left.evaluate() / self.right.evaluate()
        else:
            return self.value
```

Comment: Well, suppose you had (1 + (2 + 3)).  Wouldn't you want to evaluate (2 + 3) to get 5 before adding it to 1?

Comment: yes that is right ooo i understand thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

evaluate() is returning the value of the node unless the value of the node is an operator (+,-,*,/). If the value of the node is an operator, it takes the value of the left node and adds, subtracts, multiplies, or divides it to the value of the right node. This creates

This code is a postfix calculator that you can use to put together expressions like (2 + 4) / 2 = 3.

```
a = exprnode(2)
b = exprnode(4)
c = exprnode("+", a, b) 

d = exprnode(2)
e = exprnode("/", c, d)

print(e.evaluate())
```